# Changing launcher activity when the app is launched second time onwards android

Tags: android, android-activity, launcher

I am developing an android app where I have a launcher activity that takes the user's email id. When the user enters his email id he is redirected to another activity that asks for another user authentication in a `WebView`. After the user is successfully authenticated from this activity, the further execution starts.

Now, I want that after the user is authenticated on the second activity and he closes the app. Next time when he starts the app he should not see the launcher activity and get redirected to the second activity.

Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

My code:-

```
Animation animTranslate  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Login.this, R.anim.translate);
    animTranslate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) 
        {

                if(LoadUserEmail()==null)
                {
                    LoginBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Animation animFade  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Login.this, R.anim.fade);
                    LoginBox.startAnimation(animFade);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Details1.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }

    });
public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  // username, deviceId, deviceName parameters
                    boolean didItWork =true;

                    username = editUser.getText().toString().trim();

                    if(username.length()==0)
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid email address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        didItWork = false;
                    }


                    else
                    {
                    isUserSaved = true;
                    didItWork = true;
                    SaveUsersEmail(username);
                    checkUsername = LoadUserEmail();
}

 public void SaveUsersEmail(String username)
     {
         PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("Username",
                  username).commit();  


     }



public  String LoadUserEmail()
     {
         String username = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("Username",
                 "Please login"); 
         return username;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the authentication token in the `SharedPreferences` and use it the next time. If you're not using authentication token, you can save the credentials in the `SharedPreferences` and use them the next time.

**EDIT**

You will have to do the checking in the launcher activity. Something like (pseudo code):

```
Read values from SharedPreferences
if(values != null)
  go to some activity you want
else
  go to second activity (i.e. login activity)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done that for the second activity where the user enters his credentials in the webpage. The launcher activity just has a `EditText` field that takes the email id. The next time I start the app, it again shows me the launcher activity. I basically need to change the launcher activity after the second launch onwards. Can you provide me with an example

Comment: @user3354605 Yes, you'll have to change the code for the launcher. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: @user3354605 Did it work for you? Have you solved your issue?

Comment: No Iam still struggling on it. If I try to save the username and launch the app again, it crashes

Comment: @user3354605 you can post your code if you need more help.

Comment: @user3354605 OK, this will not work. Let's take it one step at a time. In your `onAnimationEnd()`, you are checking `if(LoadUserEmail()==null)`, so in your `LoadUserEmail()` you need to assign `null` too like `.getString("Username", null);`.

Comment: What I want to do is that when the user starts the app for the first time he is shown a animation and a login `EditText`. He enters the username and its gets saved. Next when he starts the app, he should be shown only the animation and not the edit field and directed to the second activity

Comment: @user3354605 My app has the same logic too. First make the changes I mentioned and let me know after that what issue you have.